# SSH connection refused windows 7

Tags: raspbian, ssh, xming

I have a problem connecting my raspi 2 to my laptop monitor using SSH connection. my laptop OS is windows 7.

After I put the IP address of PI, the putty shows

```
fatal error:connection refused.
```

I have try multiple times but still the same.

my PI address is: `169.254.110.48`

Comment: Can you ping the Pi? If yes try to launch Putty with the increased verbosity option -v: `putty.exe -v`

Comment: Your question is too broad. As others have pointed out this is a  link-local address. I could guess what you have done, but if you describe the physical connection you may get an answer.

Comment: You may be able to scan your network using NMap/Fing and see if you can find the Pi, otherwise it is also possible to get a serial connection to the Pi via the GPIO (and a adapter usually). Also, its worth checking whether there is a firewall anywhere on the computers/network that could block SSH

Answer (score 1):

What is determining the IP addresses that your PC and Pi are getting?  That 196.254.x.x address range is a *link-local* as per [RFC3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) one that Windows uses for [**A**utomatic **P**rivate **IP A**ddressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) which Apple calls **Bonjour**.  However, as per the Wikipedia:

> In IPv4 they are normally only used to assign IP addresses to network interfaces when no external, stateful mechanism of address configuration exists, such as the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP), or when another primary configuration method has failed. In IPv6, link-local addresses are mandatory and required for the internal functioning of various protocol components.

Given that you are able to reach here to the Stack Exchange site I would presume that you have a router that should be providing IPs, possibly in the 192.168.x.y range where x is often 0 or 1, and y is possibly 1 for the router and then goes upwards for other things connected on your LAN.

This error *can* be caused by IP address clashes, especially if some devices are set to fixed ones (for instance if they are a server/gateway and you want to fix where they are - like your broadband router) **and** your **only** *dhcp* server (normally, again, your router) has not been told to NOT use that fixed address as one for the DHCP pool.  **I'd suggest getting into your router's configuration and checking the range of addresses used for dhcp does not include any statically assigned ones configured locally on a device itself.**  Note that many routers do permit you to "reserve" a specific address for devices which you always want to have a fixed address for (e.g. I have one device used as an IPv6 tunnel gateway and local storage server which it is convenient to always be 192.168.1.2 next to the IPv4 router on 192.168.1.1) which is another way to have a fixed address AND for it to be handled by dhcp rather than by locally setting on the device itself.

Unlike the previous answer - which I don't have the reputation to comment on (yet) - I'd strongly urge you NOT to enable `PermitRootLogin without-password` UNLESS you have also sorted out a key to secure such logins.  By default Pis running Raspbian do not have a root password set so if there is external access to your LAN the Pi will be very insecure - and once you sort out your IP issues so that it is reachable it will be vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

First in terminal on your pi type `ip add` it should return `192.254.110.48` if that is the pi's local ip addres if it is then type `sudo apt-get install ssh`. Next type `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and find the line that says `PermitRootLogin without-password`, it is normally 26 lines down, and change it to `PermitRootLogin yes`, `CTRL-x, y enter` and then type `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` and hit enter, next type `ip add` grab the ip go to your computer, open putty type in your ip address, make sure that the port is 22 and hit open. Hopefuly this helps you out.

Comment: Permitting root login not a good idea for security....

Comment: unless you use a crazzy password like `i HATE my Children` or `i LOVE My Dog`

Comment: Still word based - what about `azZ6yfYnUKRwtZPEm`?

Comment: the thing is about your passwd is that we have trained computers so good to crack passwords now that they mainly look for lowercase and capital letters numbers and special characters

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to solve this problem Raspberry Pi 3.
In RPI 3 Default setting SSH Service is disabled so you want to start Thsi Service using terminal command:

> sudo service ssh start

and it is need everytime whenever your raspberry boot up so you want to add this line in  file :

**/etc/rc.local**

so, using vim editor you can add below line rc.local file

> sudo service ssh start

Answer (score -1):

Must use sudo raspi-config to start ssh service. None of the 'headless' ssh methods worked. I had to connect a screen and monitor to start ssh services. Then all fine.

Comment: You are responding to an old post and you don't specify what are the "non of the ... methods". If you have a fresh Raspbian (Nov. 2016), you might check [this method](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install/58479#58479) for headless setup.