# Know the IP but cannot SSH? PI 3

Tags: pi-3, ssh, static-ip

I just bought a raspberry pi 3 with not previous experience. I want to run my pi without keyboard and mouse.

I do have an old tv that can be used to display the output. Now this way I first got a message 'internet connection required' when I booted up.

Connected the pi with ethernet to my laptop and enabled connection sharing (which had no effect on the pi's internet connection for some reason).

So I connected the pi directly to my router. Now by some trial and error I found out the ip of my pi, in this case `192.168.2.13` when running `ping 192.168.2.13` I get responses when I plug the ethernet cable in, and none when I take it out. (name is 'recovery'?)

The problem is that I can't seem to ssh into the pi, running `ssh 192.168.2.13` returns 'Connection refused'. PuTTy can't connect to it either.

I can't seem to find a solid guide which works for me. Just wondering if it is possible at all to ssh to my pi when it's still in the selection screen?

*(I have a pi 3 currently in the NOOBS selection screen for an OS)*

Referenced guides:

- [Sharing wifi connection over ethernet headless mode](https://anwaarullah.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/sharing-wifi-internet-connection-with-raspberry-pi-through-lanethernet-headless-mode/)
- [Connecting raspberry pi without monitor beginners](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/connecting-raspberry-pi-without-monitor-beginners/)
- [Raspberry pi Topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=38618)
- [Connect raspberry pi to laptop display](https://diyhacking.com/connect-raspberry-pi-to-laptop-display/)
- [Raspberry Pi VNC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/)

Comment: Why the downvote? New to this stackexchange site and read the tour. Seems to be an appropriate question

Comment: I think you need to enable ssh in the first place through raspi-config.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/250) suggests that `ssh` is not enabled at that stage but it's from over a year ago so it could be different now.

Comment: Yes, "connection refused" indicates there is no SSH running.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question: 
[SSH not working with fresh install](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install)

Here is the [accepted answer from the user techraf, which is a quote from the raspberry pi documentation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58479/49240):

> As of the November 2016 release, Raspbian has the SSH server disabled
>   by default. You will have to enable it manually.
>
> Enter sudo raspi-config in the terminal, first select advanced
>   options, then navigate to ssh, press Enter and select Enable or
>   disable ssh server.
>
> For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named 'ssh',
>   without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card.

Comment: If you find a question has an answer under a different one, please use the "flag" link and mark the question as a duplicate, instead of repeating the content.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I couldn't flag a question because I have not enough reputation.