# Cannot connect via ssh | putty to new rPi3 and JessieLight via wired Ethernet

Tags: ssh, raspbian-jessie

Pulled a fresh rPi3 out of the cupboard and installed JessieLight (2017) on it.
**Added the file 'ssh' to the root of the sd card** to enable the by default disabled ssh; put the SD into the Pi, network cable and power; red LED on, green blinking...
rPi3 acquired IP address via DHCP; I can ping it, nmap shows port 22 is open... however, when connecting via laptop on Mint, I get an error:
ssh 
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer

If I try to connect from a windows 10 PC I get:
Network error; Software caused connection abort

I have no clue what to do next, given this is a new install, on a new Pi, without any other software than the Jessie light image and the file ssh to run a headless pi.
I have changed the SD card, wrote image, added ssh file and same result.

There are other rPis (running Jessie 2016) on the network I can connect to w/o problems.

Any help appreciated.

[edit] And no, this is not a duplicate of existing ssh problems on fresh installs.

Comment: Did you check the IP address on your new rPI by typing ifconfig command (something like eth0 or enp0)?
And you should check is it the same there and in the Putty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH not working with fresh install](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of the problem, but there is no solution. My question contains the right approach, but I still cannot connect, meaning something else is going on.

Comment: did you add the ssh file to the `root` or `boot` partition? It needs to go in the boot partition.

Comment: into boot, which is the root (top most) directory when looking at it on a windows machine, where I wrote the image to the SD card (like any other Pis before).

Comment: Is it possible you used the Windows machine to create the ssh file, and have a hidden file extension on it?

Comment: Yes, I used windows with extensions enabled as visible and it does not have a .txt extension :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up connecting a monitor to the Pi... and it showed a yellow lighting bolt at the top right conrner = indicating under voltage.
The power supply was good and sufficient, but the USB cable had only hair thin wires in it, which went in the bin and was replaced with a 22AWG (6 AUD) cable.

**Now the Pi works!**

I checked the voltage on the old cable, which dropped to 0.5V on start-up, while the better cable dropped to 4.6V at start-up.

Thank you for your input and sorry for wasting your time!

It proves the point again: if a new rPi is showing the weirdest signs of behaviour > check power supply and USB cable!