# SSH times out while attempting headless setup

Tags: pi-3, ssh, setup, headless

I'm posting again because my first attempt got marked as duplicated, [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install) did not solve my problem.

This is a brand new Raspberry Pi 3B that I'm setting up for the first time and it has be headless. First I wanted the Kali distribution but the device never showed up in the LAN. Hence, I used the standard Raspbian (2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img as today).

To be clear, I do add the `ssh` file to the in the SD, then proceed to boot the Rπ and connect it to my router. I make an `arp -a` request and see my Rπ added on 192.168.2.116:

```
localhost:~ user$ arp -a
easy.box (192.168.2.1) at 88:25:2c:9d:94:72 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
localhost (192.168.2.116) at b8:27:eb:74:64:b1 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

So, I try to SSH and after waiting I get **timed out** (=!Connection refused):

```
localhost:~ user$ ssh pi@192.168.2.116
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.116 port 22: Operation timed out
```

What's even weirder:

```
localhost:~ user$ ping -c 5 192.168.2.116
PING 192.168.2.116 (192.168.2.116): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3

--- 192.168.2.116 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

I sniffed the traffic with Wireshark and the only message the Rπ ever sends is a IGMP Membership Report, every 30 seconds or so.

The µUSB is directly plugged to the wall, so we can discard power issues.

I would appreciate any help, as I refuse to think it's a hardware problem.

Comment: Why do you think localhost is the Pi?  localhost is the computer you are using to do the ping.

Comment: I don't "think" so, I just copied from Terminal. Actually it says local host to every entry but the router IIRC.