# Starting raspberry pi for the first time using laptop

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I just bought my raspberry pi..but unfortunately i dont have a monitor or an hdmi cable so will be using my laptop to install raspbian on my raspberry pi board.
Many tutorials are regarding connecting to laptop but for that raspberry board need to be installed with raspbian os already.
So can anyone tell me how to install raspbian os on my raspberry board with a laptop for the first time.?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md also you probably want `ssh` access so see ssh section in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: `you probably want ssh access` - wouldn't you need to have a monitor+keyboard connected to the pi to set up ssh in the first place?

Comment: @JaromandaX Not required - you can [add a file to your boot partition](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58479/32756) using the machine you image your SD card with, which enables SSH.

Comment: @goobering - cool, did not know about this very useful option for headless pi's

Answer (score 1):

the SSH connection in Rasbian Jessie, after placing the image on the SD card, create an empty file in the root path / in the SD card, named as ssh, without any extension, this will activate the SSH in raspberry pi.﻿