# Headless pi SSH not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, ssh

So I tried setting up my headless pi with Raspbian like I usually do:

- Flash Raspbian to µSD (using Etcher)
- add zeroconf address to cmdline.txt (ip=169.254.10.1)
- add empty file 'ssh' to boot partition without extension

But this time, when I try to ssh into my pi (ssh pi@169.254.10.1) it says:
**ssh: connect to host 169.254.10.1 port 22: Connection refused**

Anyone who knows what might be wrong?
(the steps mentioned above are the only ones I've done)

Comment: Can you ping the Pi?

Comment: Yes, I can ping it.

Comment: May I recommend to read this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install/58479#58479

Comment: @Fabian It seems that OP already added ssh file on boot partition as suggested by your link

Comment: **Why** would you try and set a [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) address? What is the Pi connected to?

Comment: @Milliways the zeroconf address is used to connect to my pi over ssh by just connecting it with an ethernet cable to my computer. This way I can setup the main network while logged in on the pi.

Comment: Please clarify **in the body of the question** where you put the `ssh` dummy file.  There is an *edit* button for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

ssh is activated if there is an empty ssh file in the `boot` partition!

Ref.: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Comment: you are correct, but as OP stated he already created enpty ssh file in boot partition.

Comment: There is a huge difference between "root" and "boot" partition, read the question again @ChetanBhargava

Comment: @Dr. Casual: Is your empty ssh file still there? Where exactly? In some cases this file gets deleted after restart, see comments here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/

Comment: @MatsK well, I assumed that OP did a typo as his process "usually" works fine.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava And I assume that the OP can spell correct.

Comment: I indeed meant te boot partition. Everything I did usually works fine, but not this time and I can't figure out why and that really bugs me. Anyways, flashing my card again solved my problem.

Comment: Note that "boot partition" and the `/boot` directory in the second partition are not the same thing when you access the card mounted on another computer.  You want to use the former.