# I'm not able to connect my Raspberry Pi with SSH

Tags: raspbian, ssh, static-ip, raspbian-lite

I have followed [this](http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-basics-setup-without-monitor-keyboard-headless-mode/) tutorial for setting up my new Raspberry Pi. Here is what I did-

1. Download Raspbian Stretch Lite
2. Download Disk32Imager
3. Download Putty
4. Download advanced IP scanner.
5. Write Raspbian OS on SD card using diskimager
6. Connect Pi with router using Ethernet cable
7. Power up the Pi
8. Use advanced IP scanner to find IP of Pi
9. Open Putty and enter IP
   And then getting this error-

   Network error: Connection refused

My Raspberry Pi's non-routable IP is 192.168.0.2
I have also tried changing the IP address to 192.168.0.210 in DHCP Static IP configuration but still didn't work.

How can I fix it and use SSH with my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Because SSH is not enabled by default you must create empty file with name ssh (no extension) and place it in root of SD card at partition you can see from Windows.

Comment: @Misaz This step is part of the linked tutorial. Bangladesh71 Have you enabled SSH or bypassed this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because SSH is not enabled by default you must create empty file with name ssh (no extension) and place it in root of SD card at partition you can see from Windows.

Comment: duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58479/78211