# Cannot see raspberry in local network

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, raspbian-stretch, static-ip

As I stated, I'm unable to access my headless raspberry through **SSH**, even if I were able to do it before the first reboot.
The raspberry's leds are blinking but it seems like it's not connected to router.
It's currently running **Raspbian Stretch Lite** without graphical support, didn't set static IP.

All leds from RJ45 sockets are on. I know the current IP address that was given by DHCP server. I don't get replies by ping in any case. I tried `arp -a` but it does show all the other devices, except the raspberry.

Comment: You did not gave enough information. To find the reason you should ask yourselve those questions: 1. Are leds from RJ45 sockets on Raspberry on?
2. Do you know current IP address that was given to your Pi by DHCP server?
3. Is your Pi replying to pings?

Comment: How do you connect before the first reboot?

Comment: To ask for clarification, you can leave a comment rather than an answer (but you need to earn 50 rep to do this). You'll need to earn some rep from other questions and answers first, then you can post a comment here and request clarification. Answers posted here that do not answer the question will be deleted, so you'll need to answer some questions that don't require clarification first. Good luck!

Comment: If you are on the same network you can try seeing what devices are connected to the same network by typing in terminal "arp -a". It will hopefully show your device (if it knows the wifi credentials). You can then ssh using that ip address

Comment: 1. Yep, all of them are on
2. Yep, i know which is the address
3. No, not replying in any case

Comment: Tried "arp -a" but it does show all the other devices, except the raspberry.
And yes, I was able to connect before the first reboot, even enabled SSH.

Comment: Are you sure you know the address? Can you scan your network for sure?

Comment: Let me ask again: **HOW** do you connect before the first reboot? Do you use `ssh pi@<ip-adddress>`? How do you get the <ip-address>? Do you look at your DHCP server, what ip address it has given to the raspi? After reboot do you use `ssh pi@<ip-address>` again? Can you please try with `ssh -v pi@<ip-address>` and give us the output from ssh?

Comment: Yeah I did use that command, after getting the IP from the router DHCP settings (or using nmap). Anyway I managed to understand what was the problem, somehow I messed up /etc/fstab and the rasp would start in emergency mode. I tried to restore the original file and now it's all working fine. Thank you anyway, your help was appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH not working with fresh install](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install)