# Raspberry Pi Zero W Finding IP headless?

Tags: ssh, putty

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi Zero W to make a USB computer.

I've flashed an image and it appears to have booted correctly (as seen by the solid green light).

I have a MicroUSB to USB cable connecting it to my PC through the data and power port in hopes to use SSH to access it. I'm using PuTTY to do this. When I connect via the `pi@raspberrypi.local` IP address it says that there is no host.

I have Bonjour installed too. So, I'm trying to find the IP address of the Pi itself, but I'm not sure how to.

- I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W.
- I'm trying to SSH into it.
- It's connected through the data and power port to my PC.
- SSH says there is no host.

Thank you!

Comment: You write "data and power port," but the power port is *only* a power port.  If your cable is connected to the power connection, you don't have a data connection.  If your cable is connected to the USB connection, you *may* be able to "back power" the Pi that way; I haven't tried.  Could you please edit your connection to tell us a bit more about how the connections are arranged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to make an SSH connection, make sure that can your PC `ping` the raspberry pi? To check it, open terminal on your PC (the operating system does not matter) then:

```
ping raspberrypi.local
```

Or `ping` it by its IPv6:

```
ping raspberrypi
```

If the result is telling that `the host is unreachable` or `request time out`, it's a problem with your network because you have written the official raspbian image file to the SD-Card and its default hostname is `raspberrypi`.

If the ping process tells you that the `raspberrypi` host is reachable with `Reply from ...` or something else, you can make an SSH connection by `pi@raspberrypi.local` or on PuTTY, add `raspberrypi.local` as Host Name (or IP address) with default port 22.
If all of this procedure is working but still you do not have any SSH access to raspberry pi, you should make sure is the SSH enabled or not.

As your question body, you did not mention adding an `ssh` file to `boot` partition. To solve this problem, check the link below:

[How to enable SSH without a Monitor or Screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105104/44221)

---

If you are looking for a way to getting the IP address of the raspberry pi, there is a lot of IP scanner for Windows, Linux even Android and iOS. Just search about that and give it a try. Also, if the `ping raspberrypi.local` is working, you can get the exact  IP address by this command on Windows os Linux:

```
nslookup raspberrypi.local
```

The output would be something like this:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    raspberrypi.local
Address:  192.168.1.110
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the config.txt file to have the driver loaded automatically?

You need to have added the line
 *dtoverlay=dwc2*

also cmdline.txt needs to have
 *modules-load=dwc2,g_ether*

added (I put it just after the rootwait instruction).

Also, remember to add a file called ssh to the boot partition to enable SSH.

Note - do not edit these files using Windows notepad as it adds a carriage return to each line. Use Notepad++ (free download).
Take care on the spacing in cmdline.txt as well as all the above!

Comment: I have added everything above, using Notepad++ when needed. I followed a tutorial on YouTube and made my files match theirs exactly. Do you know of any way to find the pi's IP? (Headless)

Answer (score 0):

You have already done everything that **should** work.  You only need one USB cable - to the power connector. If you have a windows PC, you might try running [NirSoft's "Wireless Network Watcher"](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html), and then booting the RPi.
It will scan the network and display new devices when, and if they connect. If you are in an environment where you can disconnect other devices from your network (to avoid possible collisions), you might also give that a try.

Comment: You say 'it should work'. Please see my question https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108889/pi-zero-usb-on-the-go-cannot-connect . I would be **really** grateful for an answer. P.S. My understanding is that the USB should connect to the **data** port - the power socket has no data connections.