# Cannot SSH or use VNC (but can ping)

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, pi-4, vnc

I can't seem to SSH or connect using VNC viewer from my desktop PC to my pi 4 on raspbian, but I can ping it and connect to it on my other devices connected to my home network.

Although unlike other questions I've seen, I can SSH and connect through VNC on my laptop and my android phone. It just doesn't work on my main desktop PC (I used to be able to before though).

Comment: Because everything works on the RasPi except when using the main desktop PC, then this must be a problem of your main PC and not of the RasPi. Please look at your main PC.

Comment: *I used to be able to before though* hints something has changed - maybe that's a place to start? Can you get at the logs for SSH and put them here (putty creates a file on Windows, SHH supports verbose on Mac / Linux).  May be an issue with the known hosts file or SSH keys but without the log to show any errors I'm guessing.

Comment: Where would I be able to find these logs? I checked my PuTTY directory and couldn't find anything.

Comment: There is no PuTTY directory on a Raspberry Pi,

Comment: I'm a Mac user but Google is your friend to logging under Windows https://my.kualo.com/knowledgebase/?kbcat=0&article=888

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH not working with fresh install](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58478/ssh-not-working-with-fresh-install)